# Use Github Boilerplate as new project template and keep up with changes

Tags: git, github

I would like to use one of the `Github` boilerplate as a base template for my new project. I can clone or download a copy and work on it.

But i would like to know if it is possible to keep receiving updates from the original repo which i used as a base template.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could write a hook to pull the latest updates from the original repository into your working repository.